# How to skiped few lines and read as dataframe in pandas?

Tags: python, csv, rows

i have few files in txt. They are sep by tab but have a some trash in first few rows. I have to read all by pd.dataframe, delete all trash rows and merge together.

I'm read file by this code:
dataFromRawFile = pd.read_csv('texttt.txt', sep=",", header=None)
print(dataFromRawFile)

Files looks like:

```
[trash]: trash
[trash_umbers]:3224
trash_name
[DATA]
id    number    color
good  good      good
good  good      good
good  good      good 
good  good      good
```

how can I modify that pandas command to read data frame without all trash row? Let's say that I would like the file to be loaded from the only fixed value in all files, i.e. from "id".
How can read that file by this specific strign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to get the row number of the `id` column for each file in the directory (this assumes they're all `.txt` files; modify the condition accordingly). This can be done the following way:

```
import os

skip_rows = {}

for filename in os.listdir():
    if os.splitext(filename)[1] == '.txt':
        with open(filename) as f:
            lines = f.readlines()
            skip_rows[filename] = [index for index, line in enumerate(lines) if line[:2] == 'id'][0]
```

Now, `skip_rows` should contain the number of lines to be skipped for each file.

You can then do this:

```
dataframes = {filename: pd.read_csv(filename, skiprows=n_rows) for filename, n_rows in skip_rows.items()}
```

and read from each element in `dataframes`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `skiprows` functionality of `read_csv` or `read_table`.

In your case try `skiprows=4`

Comment: thanks for replay but i need to skip by some string. For example: read file, find lines before "id" and delete all lines above

Comment: what do you get when using skiprows=4?

Comment: I get what I want :) but some of my files have more trash lines, and I would have to modify that "skip rows = 4" in every case. Or perhaps is a possibility to find the line by string, give it a number and use that number as skip value?.

Edit:
I did it this way. Thanks for the guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `skiprows` property of pandas while using `pd.read_csv()` method.

Say for example you want to have the whole table for to be into your dataframe.

So write a function which will locate the word "id" in your file.

```
def get_loc():
with open (filename) as f:
    for num, line in enumerate(f,1):
        if 'word_to_find' in line.strip().lower():
            break
    return num
```

This will give you the location.

Then just use

```
df = pd.read_csv(yourfilename, skiprows = getloc()-1)
```